# Change a picture inside app using camera

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, contacts, implicit

Excuse me everyone. I'm sorry if my english not good, I can't speak english well :) . I want to make an android app and its look like contact app. When opening the app there are some people's name. When I click a name it will open details activity. Inside the  detail activity there is a default picture. On that picture's corner there is a button, when i click it will open the camera. But how to change the default picture with a picture that was taken with camera ?

Its my Details Activity : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0CRcpLZ5j3DSGQ4X3RkUDJ6NTg/view?usp=sharing

![Details Activity][1]

Its my code to open camera

`public void LaunchCamera(View v){
        Intent i = getIntent();
        i=new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        startActivity(i);
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:-

```
    public void LaunchCamera(View v){
        Intent i = getIntent();
        i=new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 100) {
               Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtra("data");
               yourImageView.setImageBitmap(image);
             }
      }
}
```

Comment: I was tried that code, but the default picture still not change. Is that need some permissions ? I just used permission for internet, write external storage, camera, call phone . By the way thanks for helping :)

Comment: Debug your code as well at onActivityResult if it is working or not!!

Answer (score 0):

at first you should call `startActivityForResult(i,0)` after that you should add the fallowing code to your project!

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

now your picture is in bmp that you should define like `Bitmap bmp;`